# Assign class based on current div at top of page

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, window

Im trying to assign a class to an element whenever the section that passes the top of the screen has the class 'dark' or 'light' - it works, but only once. Any advice on how I can get it to repeat for each instance?

```
var dark = $('.dark');
var light = $('.light');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > dark.position().top) {
        $('#masthead').addClass('dark');
        $('#masthead').removeClass('light');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > light.position().top) {
        $('#masthead').removeClass('dark');
        $('#masthead').addClass('light');
    }
});
```

Here's a [link to the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattress/qmadjrgz/2/).

Comment: You seem to be on the right track using scrollTop() what happens when you run it?

Comment: Thanks @Nelles, it runs for the first instance of each but will not work for the others - can't figure it out.